# How to get a drawable identifier from code

Tags: android

Having a drawable i would like to find the identifier

Layout

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/account_lock"
/>
```

Activity

```
...
TextView tv = ...;
Drawable d = tv.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
int id = d.???????
```

i have looked at `getResources().getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)` but i do not think it helps me to find it;

Comment: I am exactly not getting the question, can you please ellaborate what you required? do you want the left drawable?

Comment: i ask if i can take the identifier from the Drawable object

Answer (score 1):

The id should be accessible as R.drawable.account_lock

Comment: i ask if i can take it from the Drawable object, not where to find it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it. I don't know whether you need it to be in a subfolder of res as I have, though.

```
//In this example, I'm getting an id from the res/raw folder.
    int id = *activity.this*.getApplicationContext().getResources().getIdentifier(*filename*, "raw", *packagename*);
```